# How to match binomial expressions in R?

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match binomials, that is, bisyllabic words, sometimes hyphenated, with slightly varied syllable reduplication; the variation always concerns the first (and, possibly, second) letter in the reduplicated syllable:

```
x <- c("pow-wow", "pickwick", "easy-peasy", "nitty-gritty", "bzzzzzzz", "mmmmmm", "shish", "wedged", "yaaaaaa")
```

Here, we have said syllable reduplication in `pow-wow`, `pickwick`, `easy-peasy`, and `nitty-gritty` (which are then the expected output) but *not* in `bzzzzzzz`, `mmmmmm`, `shish`, `wedged` and `yaaaaa`.

This regex does at least manage to get rid of `wedged`(which is pronounced as one syllable) as well as monosyllabic words by requiring the presence of a vowel in the capturing group:

```
grep("\\b\\w?((?!ed)(?=[aeiou])\\w{2,})-?\\w\\w?\\1\\b$", x, value = T, perl = T)
[1] "pow-wow"      "pickwick"     "easy-peasy"   "nitty-gritty" "yaaaaa"
```

However, `yaaaaa` is getting matched too. To *not* match it my feeling is that the capturing group should be disallowed to contain two identical vowels in immediate succession but I don't know how to implement that restriction.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try `"\\b\\w(?!(.)\\1|ed)(\\w{2,})-?\\w\\w?\\2\\b"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJI0WA/1). If the first letter of the repeated part must be a vowel, try `"\\b\\w(?!(.)\\1|ed)([aeiou]\\w+)-?\\w\\w?\\2\\b"` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJI0WA/2/))

Comment: Very good! Why doesn't `"\\b\\w?(?!(.)\\1|ed)([aeiou]\\w+)-?\\w\\w?\\2\\b"` match `choochoo` (which `"\\b\\w(?!(.)\\1|ed)(\\w{2,})-?\\w\\w?\\2\\b"`does match)?

Comment: Maybe you want to only exclude repeated chars if they are not followed with the same value to the right? `"\\b\\w{0,2}(?!((.)\\2+)(?!.*\\1)|ed)([aeiou]\\w+)-?\\w\\w?\\3\\b"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJI0WA/3)

Comment: Yes, wonderful. That also picks up `wee-wee`, which the previous regexes did not! Would you care to post this as an answer and maybe add some explanation, as this is now really complex and I and other people would surely like to learn from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you want to match words that cannot contain `ed` after the initial chars and 2 or more repeated chars if the same chunk is not found farther in the string. Also, the allowed "difference" window at the start and middle is 0 to 2 characters.

You may use

```
\b\w{0,2}(?!((.)\2+)(?!.*\1)|ed)([aeiou]\w+)-?\w\w?\3\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1FeqVh/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (you may use `^` if your "words" are equal to whole string)
- `\w{0,2}` - two or more word chars (replace with `\p{L}` to only match letters)
- `(?!((.)\2+)(?!.*\1)|ed)` - no `ed` or two or more identical chars that do not repeat later in the string are allowed  immediately to the right of the current location
- `([aeiou]\w+)` - a vowel (captured in Group 3) and 1+ word chars (replace with `\p{L}` to only match letters)
- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `\w\w?` - 1 or 2 word charsd
- `\3`  - same value as captured in Group 3
- `\b` - a word boundary (you may use `$` if your "words" are equal to whole string)